# A Rational Game (Question on Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

This post is to set forth a little game that attempts to demonstrate something that I find to be intriguing about the real numbers.  The game is one that takes place in a theoretical sense only.  It starts by assuming we have two pieces of paper.  On each is a line segment of length two:  [0,2].  Each piece of paper is then stuck to a wall, one just above the other, so that the line segments on each piece of paper are perfectly aligned.  This means the line segments on each piece of paper run parallel to each other and drawing a vertical line between each 0 and each 2 would form a rectangle.

On the upper line segment we mark two numbers, $r$ and $r+1$, where:

$$r \in \, (0,1\, ) \text{ and } r \notin \mathbb{Q}$$

On the lower line segment we mark two more numbers, $r’$ and $r’+1$, where:

$$r’ > r,$$
$$r’ \in \, (0,1\, ),$$
$$r’ \notin \mathbb{Q}, \text{ and}$$
$$r’ - r \notin \mathbb{Q}$$

We are now ready to start our game.  The object of the game is to slide the top piece of paper horizontally to the right so as to make all of the rational numbers in $\, (r,r+1\, )$ align vertically with all of the rational numbers in $\, (r’,r’+1\, )$.  Fortunately, for purposes of this game, we are given the ability to slide ‘perfectly’ given that this game takes place only in a theoretical sense.

Despite our ability to slide the uppermost piece of paper with God-like precision, it is seemingly still impossible to win the game.  The length that we would have to slide the upper piece of paper to the right must be a rational number because sliding an irrational length to the right would imply that none of the rational numbers align (ie, a rational plus an irrational will always be irrational).  However, if we slide a rational length to the right, then $r$ and $r’$ could not be vertically aligned.  In that case, the Archimedean property of the real numbers would ensure that an infinite number of rational numbers on each line segment could also not be vertically aligned.*1*

**At first glance there may not be much to discuss here as we're touching on only the basics of real analysis.  But, I want to point out a few things that I find confusing if not paradoxical:**

1)      The unaligned rationals come in pairs.  For any given
$$q \in A = \{r’-r+p : p \in \, (r,r+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \}$$
let $q’$ be the
$$q’ \in \, (r’, r’+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that } \{q'-p : p \in \,(r’,r’+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \} = \{q-p : p \in A \}$$

2)      When $r$ and $r’$ are aligned, the rationals in $\, (r,r+1\, )$ and $\, (r’,r’+1\, )$ are not.  This means that there must exist a space between each pair of unaligned rationals $q$ and $q’$ (otherwise they would align).

3)      When $r$ and $r’$ are aligned, we can define the distance $x = |q’-q|$ and note simply that the distance $x$ must be an irrational number because the distance between a rational number and an irrational number is always irrational (note that $q$ now holds an irrational position on the number line because $r$ and $r’$ are aligned).  We can also note that since all of the rationals exist within $r’$ and $r’+1$ when $r$ and $r'$ are aligned, shifting the upper piece of paper by a distance of $x$ so as to make all of the rationals align would not cause any to fall outside of $\, (r’,r’+1\, )$.

4)      We can then assert that of the two distances, $r’-r+x$ and $r’-r-x$, at least one is a rational number.  Further, we can assert that one of the two distances is the distance we must slide the piece of paper so as to win the game.  Take this last assertion as more of a question, because it contradicts the Archimedean property.  What, if anything, is wrong with my logic?

References:

1  The proof that there is a rational between any two irrationals stems from the Archimedean property.  See, e.g., Theorems 1.1.4 and 1.1.6 on pages 5 and 6 of the following:  Trench, W. (2013). Introduction to Real Analysis. Available at http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF

Comment: If I understood correctly, for the pieces of paper $(r,r+1)$ and $(r',r'+1)$ to align at all, we would need to slide the top piece of paper exactly $r'-r$ units to the right, which makes the whole thing kind of trivial and obviously impossible.

Comment: We don't need $\, (r, r+1\, )$ and $\, (r', r'+1\, )$ to align exactly, we just need the rationals in them to align exactly.

Comment: Both pieces have length one, so if the pieces don't align exactly there will certainly be rationals from one piece of paper that lie outside the corresponding piece.

Comment: Yes, as was acknowledged in the question, your line of thinking (the proof that there is a rational between any two irrationals) is one that stems from the Archimedean property.  So I ask, potentially naively or in the very least in a philosophical sense:  the difference in cardinalities between the irrationals and rationals suggests that our number line may be 'flooded' with irrationals as compared to rationals.  The above suggests there is space between the unaligned rationals.  What fills that space?  Is there really a rational between each set of irrationals?

Comment: There is indeed a rational between each pair of irrationals, though there are many more irrationals than rationals. Indeed, *every* nonempty interval contains countably many rationals and uncountably many rationals.

Comment: I agree that the cardinality of the rationals is less than the irrationals, but that is not the same as saying there are "many more" irrationals than rationals (that I can't agree with because I have no idea what you mean by "more," but I will agree that the difference in cardinalities suggests there are more irrationals than rationals).  The rest of what you said I already did too in the above question...  Just as Achilles must catch up to the tortoise in Zeno's paradoxes, the math suggests otherwise.  Is the infinite plaguing us when it comes to the Archimedean property too & can we align?

Comment: Yes, the number line is 'flooded' with irrationals in the sense that for an interval $I$ of length $l$, the set of irrationals on $I$ has measure $l$ and the rational on $I$ have measure $0$. So, for instance, if you could pick a number uniformly at random on $I$, it would be rational with probability $0$ and irrational with probability $1$.

Comment: I don't see a real question here, sorry

Comment: I added so as to make the question clear and answerable with a "yes" or "no," hopefully followed by an explanation.

Comment: I find this really difficult to follow once you start talking about $q'$.  I have no idea what your "process" is attempting to achieve.  What is a "suitable" $q'$? What do the inequalities $z+x>r'+1$ and $z-x<r'$ have to do with anything?

Comment: You mention finding $q'$ which has a "minimum possible distance" from $q$.  This is, of course, impossible, and I think that is why you think something is wrong with what you are doing?  But I don't understand what you are doing--nothing you are doing seems to have any relation whatsoever to finding the "minimal possible distance".

Comment: If the rationals were aligned per the game's instruction, then $q' \in \, (r',r'+1\, )$ would be, for a given $q \in \, (r,r+1\, )$, the rational that $q$ aligns with.  The unaligned rationals come in pairs.  We know there is a space between each unaligned pair of rationals (otherwise they would align), so despite our inability to compute it, the "minimum possible distance" must exist.  You say "impossible," but that is like asserting Achilles never catches the tortoise even though we know he does (Zeno's paradoxes).  I say that the distance is seemingly "incomputable," but not nonexistent.

Comment: OK, there is a distance between $q$ and $q'$...but what on earth do you mean in calling it "minimum possible"?  And what does that have to do with the rest of your post?

Comment: To put it another way, the phrase "minimum possible" implies that there is some range of "possibilities" among which it is supposed to be the minimum.  I have no idea what this range is supposed to be (or why you think this range should have a minimum, as there are plenty of sets of real numbers that don't have a minimum).

Comment: If you admit there is a distance between $q$ and $q'$, then let's call that distance $x$ and note simply that it is an irrational distance.  To win the game, we now know that we must slide the paper a distance of $r'-r+x$ or $r'-r-x$, and that both of those distances are rational distances.

Comment: The above should assert that of the two distances $r'-r+x$ and $r'-r-x$, at least one of them is a rational distance and at least one of them would be the distance we must slide the paper in order to win the game.  I don't mean to assert necessarily that both distances would be rational distances and I never meant to imply that either distance could be traversed so as to win the game (presumably, one would work while the other could not).

Comment: The question now ensures that $q'$ is well defined.  Sorry for the edits.  I'm not a regular mathematician and still learning to be more precise.

Comment: Why do you think $q'$ is uniquely defined? and why do you think $x$ is constant over all 'unaligned pairs'? I would zero in on proving those two assertions.

Comment: As to $x$ being constant over all unaligned pairs, I could run the game with the object being only the alignment of the dyadic rationals as opposed to all of them.  If the dyadic rationals were aligned, all the others would be too though right?  I didn't think it made a difference.  I'll think more about why $q'$ is or is not uniquely defined and see if I can't zero in on what you're asserting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply false that "the unaligned rationals come in pairs" as you claim: that is, there is no $q'$ with the property you mention in (1).  Indeed, observe that $$\sup \{q'-p : p \in \,(r’,r’+1\, ) \cap \mathbb{Q} \}=q'-r'$$ and $$\sup \{q-p : p \in A \}=q-(r'-r+r)=q-r'.$$  So if these two sets are to be equal, we must have $q'=q$, which is impossible because $q$ is irrational and $q'$ is rational.